# R - confidence interval of the fitted data rq from withReplicates results?

Tags: r, survey, confidence-interval, statistics-bootstrap, quantile-regression

please, how to calculate confidence interval of the fitted data quantile regression from withReplicates results?

Predict simply does not work:

```
"Error in UseMethod("predict") :    no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "svrepstat"
```

I can find literally nothing anywhere about predictions and confidence intervals from a withReplicates result (contains variance-covariance matrix).

It is all about a complex survey research with nests, stratified, fpc, subsets etc.